# Creating a new column every time a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe like this (265 rows total):

```
FD
0.5
0.8
0.9
0.4
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new column every time FD is greater than 0.7. The columns need to have a dummy coded format (e.g. put a 1 when FD is greater and put 0 for the remaining rows) and each column to be called outlier with an index suffix.

Essentially this:

```
FD   outlier1 outlier2 outlier 3 ...
0.5    1         0        0
0.8    0         1        0
0.9    0         0        0
0.4    0         0        1
```

I've managed to create a new column which flags each time FD is greater than 0.7:

```
  outlier = []
for row in df['FD']:
    if row > 0.7: outlier.append('1')
    elseif row < 0.7@ outlier.append('0')

    else: outlier.append('0')
```

However, it only creates one column:

```
FD   outlier
0.5    0 
0.8    1
0.9    1
0.4    0
```

Due to the specificity of my problem, as well to being new to python, I'm finding it hard to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear to me why your preferred example output has a 1 for rows with FD of 0.5 and FD of 0.4; and none for FD equals to 0.9. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Is this an encoding problem for classification? Because scikit-learn may have some built-in utilities for this (although it can also be done with just Pandas).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a nicer way to do this using Pandas, but this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'FD': [0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.4]})

col = 1
for i, row in enumerate(df['FD']):
    if row > 0.7:
        df[f'outlier{col}'] = 0
        df.at[i, f'outlier{col}'] = 1
        col += 1

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
   FD          outlier1  outlier2
0  0.5         0         0
1  0.8         1         0
2  0.9         0         1
3  0.4         0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.4]})
condition1 = df['A'] > 0.7
i = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] > 0.7:
        df[f'outlier{i}'] = np.where(condition1, 1, 0)
    i += 1

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That does not look like the output OP wants.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal i was assuming that end goal was similar to the OP's last table

Comment: It would work if you substituted the condition with `row['A'] == df['A']`, but it'd probably be much faster to just create a 0 column and set the proper row to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might resolve your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd1=pd.DataFrame({"FD":[0.5,0.8,0.9,0.4]})
out=1;
for i in range(len(pd1.FD)):
  temp = np.zeros((len(pd1.FD),), dtype=int)
  if(pd1.FD[i]>0.7):
      temp[i] = 1
      pd1["outlier" + str(out)] = temp
      out+=1;
print(pd1)
```

Output:

```
    FD  outlier1  outlier2
0  0.5         0         0
1  0.8         1         0
2  0.9         0         1
3  0.4         0         0
```

Comment: Would personally put the `temp` definition inside the if statement. Kind of wasteful if there are only a handful of outliers in the dataframe.